# libdb4.8++ is no longer available

Tags: 12.04, installation, libraries, qt-creator

I'm trying to use QT-Creator to build a program and I get the message that `libdb4.8++` is needed and is not available.

I've tried to use `libdb5.1` and `libdb4.8` but it still asks for `libdb4.8++`

I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. What version of Ubuntu would be compatible with `libdb4.8++` if there is no way to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu lucid (10.04) did have `libdb4.8++`, and by adding an entry for it to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you can install it:

```
(echo deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted universe multiverse; echo deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted universe multiverse; echo deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted universe multiverse) | sudo sh -c 'cat >>/etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8++
```