# Fixing libtool for -rpath problems

Tags: 14.04, bitcoin

Hello i need to compile bitcoin on ubuntu 14.04 64bits but i have always this error 'Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.'

I installed all dependency

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool autotools-dev autoconf pkg-config libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get install libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev
```

like this [libdb4.8++ is no longer available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290094/libdb4-8-is-no-longer-available)

```
sudo apt-get install miniupnpc

$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
...
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libsecp256k1.pc
config.status: creating src/libsecp256k1-config.h
config.status: src/libsecp256k1-config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.
```

What is solution for fixe this error plz ? 
Thanks

Comment: The Git version?

Comment: Yes its from git i have just clone this https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message `Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.` isn't an error.

1. The easiest thing to do is to install `bitcoin` via a PPA:

   ```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install bitcoin
   ```

The correct way of what you're trying to do, is:

2. Simply run `make`.

   And here is the part in `configure`

   ```
   dnl Taken from https://wiki.debian.org/RpathIssue
   case $host in
      *-*-linux-gnu)
      AC_MSG_RESULT([Fixing libtool for -rpath problems.])
      sed < libtool > libtool-2 \
    's/^hardcode_libdir_flag_spec.*$'/'hardcode_libdir_flag_spec=" -D__LIBTOOL_IS_A_FOOL__ "/'
      mv libtool-2 libtool
      chmod 755 libtool
    ;;
   esac
   ```

Comment: Oh Thanks you A.B but its not a problem if path not correct ?

Comment: Fixing means, the problem is fixed via `sed < libtool > libtool-2 \
 's/^hardcode_libdir_flag_spec.*$'/'hardcode_libdir_flag_spec=" -D__LIBTOOL_IS_A_FOOL__ "/'
   mv libtool-2 libtool
   chmod 755 libtool`